# Groupby transform to list in pandas does not work

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

Best described with an example

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
  'a'   : ['A','B','C','A','B','C','A','B','C'],
  'b': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]}
)
```

And i want to create a column that contains in a `list` the elements of column `b` by group of column `a`

resulting in the following

```
   a    b      c
0  A    1  [1, 4, 7]
1  A    4  [1, 4, 7]
2  A    7  [1, 4, 7]
3  B    2  [2, 5, 8]
4  B    5  [2, 5, 8]
5  B    8  [2, 5, 8]
6  C    3  [3, 6, 9]
7  C    6  [3, 6, 9]
8  C    9  [3, 6, 9]
```

I can do this with `groupby` and `apply` or `agg` and then joining the dataframes like so

```
df_tmp = df.groupby('a')['b'].agg(list).reset_index()
df.merge(df_tmp, on='a')
```

But i would also be expecting to do the same with `transform`

```
df['c'] = df.groupby('a')['b'].transform(list)
```

but the column `c` is the same as column `b`

Also the following

```
df.groupby('a')['b'].transform(lambda x: len(x))
```

return a series with the values `3` i.e. the length of the grouped elements is 3 (to be expected)

Also this

```
df.groupby('a')['b'].transform(lambda x: list(x))
```

does not provide the expected result.

So to my question, how can i obtain the desired result with groupby and tranform

`pandas` version is 1.0.5

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I come up one fix with below. PS : it should something wrong with `transform` , when the object type is `list` `tuple` or `set`..

```
df.groupby('a')['b'].transform(lambda x : [x.tolist()]*len(x))
Out[226]: 
0    [1, 4, 7]
1    [1, 4, 7]
2    [1, 4, 7]
3    [2, 5, 8]
4    [2, 5, 8]
5    [2, 5, 8]
6    [3, 6, 9]
7    [3, 6, 9]
8    [3, 6, 9]
Name: b, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Could you pls expain what x.tolist() is?

Comment: @dimitris_ps make the group series to list.

Comment: One more q. Why do we need to multiply with the length. I have the error without it but i cannot understand why

Comment: @dimitris_ps since the transform will unpack the list, when we multiple the length , we create the same value multiple time, after unpack with transform, we have each sub_list as output for each row

Answer (score 9):

Interesting problem, not sure what happens with `transform` in the background. One go-around is to `map` with `groupby().agg()`:

```
df['c'] = df['a'].map(df.groupby('a')['b'].agg(list))
```

Output:

```
   a  b          c
0  A  1  [1, 4, 7]
1  B  2  [2, 5, 8]
2  C  3  [3, 6, 9]
3  A  4  [1, 4, 7]
4  B  5  [2, 5, 8]
5  C  6  [3, 6, 9]
6  A  7  [1, 4, 7]
7  B  8  [2, 5, 8]
8  C  9  [3, 6, 9]
```

Comment: Could this answer be extended or generalized if we would like to group by more than a single column? For example: `.map(df.groupby(by=['a1', 'a2', 'a3'])['b'].agg(list))`