# Concatenate values in a column by group as a list and assigning it to a variable in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
game = pd.DataFrame({
    'team': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
    'members': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
})
game
```

```
  team  members
0    A        1
1    A        2
2    B        3
3    B        4
4    C        5
5    C        6
6    C        7
```

I would like to concatenate the values from column 'members' by group 'team' to form a list, and attach them to a new variable all_team_members. The expected results are:

```
  team  members  all_team_members
0    A        1            [1, 2]
1    A        2            [1, 2]
2    B        3            [3, 4]
3    B        4            [3, 4]
4    C        5         [5, 6, 7]
5    C        6         [5, 6, 7]
6    C        7         [5, 6, 7]
```

I have the following code that I thought would work, but results are not as expected

```
game['all_teamm_members'] = game.groupby('team').members.transform(lambda x : x.tolist())
```

P.S.: I know I can accomplish this by first use `game.groupby('team').members.apply(lambda x : x.tolist())` to create the list at unique group ('team') level and then merge the dataframe back to the original dataframe, however I am really curious how I can accomplish this using `transform()`

Comment: I think this is a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62458837/groupby-transform-to-list-in-pandas-does-not-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.apply.html#pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate) and [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
game['all_team_members'] = game['team'].map(game.groupby('team')['members']
                                                .agg(list))
```

Using [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html), you have to manually repeat the lists otherwise it's expanded back to individual rows:

```
game['all_team_members'] = (game.groupby('team')['members']
                                .transform(lambda x: [list(x)]*len(x))
                           )
```

Note that in the two approaches above, all lists within a group are the same object (which can be an advantage if you don't plan to mutate them).

To have copies (less efficient):

```
game['all_team_members'] = (game.groupby('team')['members']
                                .transform(lambda x: [list(x) for _ in 
                                                      range(len(x))])
                           )
```

Output:

```
  team  members all_team_members
0    A        1           [1, 2]
1    A        2           [1, 2]
2    B        3           [3, 4]
3    B        4           [3, 4]
4    C        5        [5, 6, 7]
5    C        6        [5, 6, 7]
6    C        7        [5, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code:

```
game['all_team_members'] = game['team'].map(game.groupby(by=['team'])['members'].agg(list))
```